# Undot Array with Wildcards in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

In Laravel, I'm performing a JSON map where I need to transform a JSON to a different schema. To do that I'm following these steps:

1. Dot the array with Arr::dot helper. This way I have this result, example:

```php
array(11) {
  ["0.identificador"]=>
  int(1)
  ["0.nome_completo"]=>
  string(8) "John Doe"
  ["0.email"]=>
  string(11) "j@email.com"
  ["0.empresa.razao_social"]=>
  string(11) "ABC Company"
  ["0.empresa.endereco"]=>
  string(11) "123 Main St"
  ["0.pedidos.0.SKU"]=>
  int(1)
  ["0.pedidos.0.descricao"]=>
  string(5) "Shoes"
  ["0.pedidos.0.qtd"]=>
  int(2)
  ["0.pedidos.1.SKU"]=>
  int(2)
  ["0.pedidos.1.descricao"]=>
  string(5) "Shirt"
  ["0.pedidos.1.qtd"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

2. Iterate through the dotted array and compare with my keys map. If they match, I set the value with the mapped key.

My mapping looks like this:

```php
array(8) {
    ["*.identificador"]=> string(4) "*.id"
    ["*.nome_completo"]=> string(6) "*.name"
    ["*.empresa"]=> string(9) "*.company"
    ["*.empresa.razao_social"]=> string(14) "*.company.name"
    ["*.empresa.endereco"]=> string(17) "*.company.address"
    ["*.pedidos.*.SKU"]=> string(13) "*.orders.*.id"
    ["*.pedidos.*.descricao"]=> string(18) "*.orders.*.product"
    ["*.pedidos.*.qtd"]=> string(19) "*.orders.*.quantity"
  }
```

And this is what my code looks like so far:

```php
$payload = [
    [
        "identificador" => 1,
        "nome_completo" => "John Doe",
        "email" => "j@email.com",
        "empresa" => [
            "razao_social" => "ABC Company",
            "endereco" => "123 Main St"
        ],
        "pedidos" => [
            [
                "SKU" => 1,
                "descricao" => "Shoes",
                "qtd" => 2
            ],
            [
                "SKU" => 2,
                "descricao" => "Shirt",
                "qtd" => 1
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$dottedPayload = Arr::dot($payload);

$transformedPayload = [];
foreach ($dottedPayload as $key => $value) {
    $newKey = preg_replace('/\d+./', '*.', $key);
    $newKey = preg_replace('/\.\d+\./', '.*.', $newKey);
    $newKey = preg_replace('/\.\d+$/', '.*', $newKey);

    $mappedKey = $mappingConfig[$newKey] ?? $key;

    data_fill($transformedPayload, $mappedKey, $value);
}
```

The output I have is this:

```php
array(2) {
  ["*"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
    ["company"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(11) "ABC Company"
      ["address"]=>
      string(11) "123 Main St"
    }
    ["orders"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["*"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(2)
        ["product"]=>
        string(5) "Shirt"
        ["quantity"]=>
        int(1)
      }
    }
  }
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(11) "j@email.com"
  }
}
```

But this is the expected:

```php
$expectedResult = [
    [
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "John Doe",
        "email" => "j@email.com",
        "company" => [
            "name" => "ABC Company",
            "address" => "123 Main St"
        ],
        "orders" => [
            [
                "id" => 1,
                "product" => "Shoes",
                "quantity" => 2
            ],
            [
                "id" => 2,
                "product" => "Shirt",
                "quantity" => 1
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

How can I properly undot the array after the mapping, with the wildcards, setting the indexes correctly? Any other suggestions to perform this JSON mapping are also welcomed.

Comment: "Undot Array in Laravel" Have you tried [Arr::undot](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/helpers#method-array-undot) method?

Comment: Yes! I tried all the helpers alreafy  but could not achieve the expected result. I wonder if it's possible without having to write a custom recursive function to handle the wildcards

Answer (score 1):

I like to implement data mapping using the [Spatie Laravel Data](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-data/v4/introduction) package.

The Spatie package uses classes to define data objects which are filled from arrays or json data. The names of the properties are the field names you want to use in your code and the package provides a [MapInputName](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-data/v4/as-a-data-transfer-object/mapping-property-names) attribute modifier to automatically translate incoming data names.

First we define the data classes and the field mapping:

```
use Spatie\LaravelData\Attributes\DataCollectionOf;
use Spatie\LaravelData\Data;
use Spatie\LaravelData\Attributes\MapInputName;
use Spatie\LaravelData\DataCollection;

class Company extends Data
{
  public function __construct(
    #[MapInputName('razao_social')] 
    public string $name,
    #[MapInputName('endereco')] 
    public string $address
  ) { }
}

class Order extends Data
{
  public function __construct(
    #[MapInputName('SKU')] 
    public int $id,
    #[MapInputName('descricao')] 
    public string $product,
    #[MapInputName('qtd')] 
    public int $quantity
  ) { }
}

class Payload extends Data
{
  public function __construct(
    #[MapInputName('identificador')] 
    public int $id,
    #[MapInputName('nome_completo')] 
    public string $name,
    #[MapInputName('empresa')]
    public Company $company,
    #[MapInputName('pedidos')]
    #[DataCollectionOf(Order::class)]
    public DataCollection $orders
  ) { }
}
```

When you receive the payload data pass it to the static constructor `from(...)` or use [dependency injection](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-data/v4/as-a-data-transfer-object/request-to-data-object) to get data from a Request:

```
$payload = [
    [
        "identificador" => 1,
        "nome_completo" => "John Doe",
        "email" => "j@email.com",
        "empresa" => [
            "razao_social" => "ABC Company",
            "endereco" => "123 Main St"
        ],
        "pedidos" => [
            [
                "SKU" => 1,
                "descricao" => "Shoes",
                "qtd" => 2
            ],
            [
                "SKU" => 2,
                "descricao" => "Shirt",
                "qtd" => 1
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

Payload::from($payload[0])->toArray();
```

The `toArray` function gives the output:

```
[
  "id" => 1,
  "name" => "John Doe",
  "company" => [
    "name" => "ABC Company",
    "address" => "123 Main St",
  ],
  "orders" => [
    [
      "id" => 1,
      "product" => "Shoes",
      "quantity" => 2,
    ],
    [
      "id" => 2,
      "product" => "Shirt",
      "quantity" => 1,
    ],
  ],
]
```

Not only does the package provide these mappings but it can also [validate](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-data/v4/validation/introduction) the data through attribute modifiers and be passed to `Model::create` to make Eloquent objects easily.